# jquery 1.9, get current selector inside each

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

in jquery 1.9 (and beyond), how do I get the name of the selector that matched an element from inside an each?

```
$("[data='load-something'],.do-something,aside,#something-else").each(function(index,el){
    // want to know if this element matched because of the id, class, or data element, etc
});
```

Answer (score 3):

You could do it like this...

```
var selectors = ["[data='load-something']",
                 ".do-something", 
                 "aside",
                 "#something-else"];

$(selectors.join(",")).each(function() {

   var element = $(this);

   if (element.is(selectors[0]) {
       // ...and so forth.
   } 

});
```

It's kind of messy, so if you can do it more elegantly, please do.

Comment: You are missing something in selectors initialization
["[data='load-something']", ".do-something", "aside", "#something-else"]; . Apart from that awsome answer

Answer (score 0):

Check

```
$(el).attr("data") //="load-something"
$(el).attr("class") //="do-something"
$(el).prop("tagName") //="aside"
$(el).attr("id"); //="something-else"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$("[data='load-something'],.do-something,aside,#something-else").each(function(index,el){
    if($(this).attr('data')=='load-something')
        //called via data
    else if($(this).hasClass()=='do-something')
        //called via class
    else if($(this).prop('tagName')=='aside' || $(this).prop('tagName')=='ASIDE')
        //called via aside
    else 
        //called via id
});
```